# download vpn device script configuration on azure resource manager vlan

Tags: vpn, azure, vlan

I am trying to get the VPN configurationa of a VLAN e.g Encryption Algorithm on the new azure resource manager VLAN (as opposed to the classic VLAN)

I used to get these configuration from a classic VLAN by downloading the VPN device configuration script, which was even more helpful since i got the script to connect to my VLAN from a specific device. See the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXz50.jpg

Currently I have a resource manager VLAN connected to a VM via a network interface, How do i get the configuration of the VLAN and/or device script like the way to used to get from a classic VLAN. See the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJnB7.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with ARM.

Anyway, all you need relative to the configuration can be found in the link below, including samples for Cisco and Juniper. Just need to replace the example values with your own.

**About VPN devices for site-to-site virtual network connections**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-about-vpn-devices/

**Azure Vpn Samples**

https://github.com/Azure/Azure-vpn-config-samples